# Using withEnv in a declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to run docker command in my declarative pipeline, to install docker env on my slave machine i'm trying to use docker commons plugin "https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-commons/", but no success.

Further research i have got below link mentioning how to use this plugin.

https://automatingguy.com/2017/11/06/jenkins-pipelines-simple-delivery-flow/

I have configured docker in manage jenkins -> global tool configuration, but dont find how to use below section in my declarative pipeline of jenkins, i think below structure/syntax will work for scripted jenkins pipeline

```
def dockerTool = tool name: 'docker', type: 
'org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.tools.DockerTool'
withEnv(["DOCKER=${dockerTool}/bin"]) {
   stages{}
}
```

Can someone pls help, how i can use docker common tool in declarative pipeline of jenkins.
Note: I cannot switch to scripted pipeline due to standardization with other projects

Comment: Have you tried enclosing this block in script?  Whole pipeline stays as declarative, only the portion will be scripted. ```pipeline { stages { stage('my stage'){steps { script {  dockerTool = tool name: 'docker', type: 
'org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.tools.DockerTool'
withEnv(["DOCKER=${dockerTool}/bin"]) {
   
}}}}}}```

Comment: Thanks Ram for ur comment, I have added below stage in my script   'stage('my stage'){
   steps{
    script{
     def dockerTool = toolname: 'docker', type: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.tools.DockerTool'
      withEnv(["DOCKER=${dockerTool}/bin"]){
       sh "docker version" 
     }
    }
   }
     } ' but failed with error org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 40: expecting '}', found ':' @ line 40, column 30.
       def dockerTool = toolname: 'docker', type: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.tools.DockerTool'

Comment: seems the syntax to add the def and scripts to use with withEnv is different in declarative pipeline

Comment: You cannot use def. remove def and try.

Comment: @Kalim Did you find solution for this? I have the same problem.The official documentation, https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-commons/#documentation is not working for me either.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('test') {
            steps{
                script{
                    test_env="this is test env"
                    withEnv(["myEnv=${test_env}"]){
                        echo "${env.myEnv}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, actually i already tried that and got same same error. Again i checked with below stage in my pipeline and same error occured, seems to be problem with colon and brackets. find my code and error

Comment: '       stage('Docker Test') {
            steps{
                script{
            dockerTool=toolname: 'docker', type: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.tools.DockerTool'
                    withEnv(["DOCKER=${dockerTool}"]){
                        echo "docker version"
                    }
                }
            }
        }'       org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 40: expecting '}', found ':' @ line 40, column 32.

Comment: ok. I assumed that you have issue in using the ENV. Could you please elaborate, what are you actually trying to do? Are you trying to install docker on slave through pipeline? Why do you actually need a path to the docker binaries? Just to be sure that, I wont drive you to a wrong direction.

Comment: Well i'm trying to manage my installation on slave machine via jenkins, so that 3rd party software dependency does not be on slave machine and my job should be independent. Well I'm already doing that for maven build jobs by configuring in "global tool configuration" of jenkins and using below code in my pipeline job.      'withEnv( ["PATH+MAVEN=${tool "maven3.6"}/bin"] ){
    sh "mvn clean install"
    }'

Answer (score 0):

I have this feeling that you are don't need to use either `withEnv` or `docker commons`. Have you seen this? https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/
There are plenty of good examples of how to use docker with Jenkinsfile.

My attempt to answer your question (if I got it right), if you are asking about declarative equivalent for scripted `withEnv`, then probably you are looking for `environment {}`? Something like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        DOCKER = "${dockerTool}/bin"
    }

    stages {
        stage('One') {
            steps {
              // steps here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working declarative pipeline solution as of [Docker Commons v1.17](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-commons/)

Note: the tool name, `dockerTool` is a keyword and *docker-19.03.11* is name I gave my installation in Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration page.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        dockerTool 'docker-19.03.11'
    }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh'''
                    echo 'FROM mongo:3.2' > Dockerfile
                    echo 'CMD ["/bin/echo", "HELLO WORLD...."]' >> Dockerfile
                '''
                script {
                    docker.withRegistry('http://192.168.99.100:5000/v2/') {
                        def image = docker.build('test/helloworld2:$BUILD_NUMBER')
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]